# How to Install Python 3.6 on RHEL 4 Enterprise Edition without Internet Access and no root access?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rhel

I'm trying to install a 3.6 python version on a RHEL 4 Enterprise edition that already have a 2.3 python version, however, I have no internet access nor a root access?
Also I'd like to install some libraries the same conditions applied.

I'm a beginner so please help me

Comment: There is a tutorial for instaling python on an offline computer at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/el/SSWTQQ_2.0.3/install/t_si_pythonpackagesoffline.html . Root access is required in this tutorial however.

Comment: @Michael_H thank you but I have no root access on the RHEL 4 computer

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that RHEL 4 is 16+ years old and Python 3 didn't exist then. Can you install a newer RHEL version via a usb/other? The latest version is RHEL 8.

Comment: No, I actually have to use RHEL 4